# Delphi XE2 64 bit app and Application Verifier fails

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2

I hope someone can explain this to me? All 64 bit apps I compile will fail when using [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20028) with just the default settings in Application Verifier. Here is sample of hello world dpr:

```
program HelloWorld;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

begin
  try
     Writeln('Hello, World!');
     Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

As I see this it fails on the Int 3 (first chance) that Application Verifier throws when the app is started? Why does this fail in x64 and not x86? And is there a way to stop this?
I must have missed something in the x64 documentation cause I am truly lost at this behavior.

Thanks to all and any who can answer this for me.

Grandpa

Comment: Have you tried to run application and app verifier both in raised mode (with admin privileges)?

Comment: What happens if you remove the try..except?

Comment: @RRUZ
Sorry I have taken so long to respond, weather went south here. Running with higher privileges does not matter.

Comment: @Remko
Leaving out the exception trap does not help either.

Comment: I can simply start a new application, a hello world form app nothing but main form, and it will fail also. Any app compiled for x64 this happens to and x86 is fine. I have read on MS site that they consider x86 as handling exceptions incorrectly and are trying to fix this in x64. I personally do not mind this since I can of course catch the second chance exceptions. However my client insists that this be corrected and the software I am supplying will run under Application Verifier. So I am thinking there was something trivial I was missing with x64.

Comment: After resetting in the IDE Application Verifier shows no errors. I am puzzled as to why the debugger (Delphi) just ignores the Int 3 in x86 and it is caught in x64 which leads me to believe it is not set in x86 and is in x64 by Application Verifier. Sorry to be so long but want to give an honest answer to my client and I have not a clue. Thanks for all the help I can get.

Sorry this is so sloppy and I do not know how to post correctly and I am really hoping to find a solution to this. Thanks again to all.

Comment: Oops, I forgot this:
I can emulate debugging in an oncreate event and trap the Int 3 from Application Verifier but my hello world app hangs, in loop I think, and never gets shown. Then the rest was...After resetting in the IDE Application Verifier shows no errors.

Comment: Does this happen to anyone else if compiling the above app? I have reinstalled Rad Studio so many times, thinking it could be an installation problem, that I have even met my limit on registering. I am using Update 3 also and I simply do not understand if it is all machines here, Borland problem or Application Verifier problem. If anyone has a clue I am open to any and all help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by installing Application Verifier 4.1.1078. Was using 4.0.0665 and it will 'always' fail. Version 4.1.1078 works as expected after turning off anti-virus